# Problem with function that is not working in C

Tags: c, function, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    
    float lp=0;
    float cp=0;
    char rc[5];
    int yes=0;
    int country=0;
    char correct[5];
    int mod=0;
    float FunLength(float *lp);
    
          
    printf("Please follow the steps:\n")
                                                                    
    printf("------------------------------------------------ 1\n");
    printf("Enter Lenght:\n");
    float FunLength(float *lp);
    
    do{ 
        printf("-------------------------------------------------2\n");
        printf("do you know the circumference?: \n");
        scanf("%s",rc);
        if(!strcmp(rc,"yes")){
            yes=1;
            break;
        }
        if(!strcmp(rc,"no")){
            yes=2;
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("You have to write 'yes' or 'no'\n");
            printf("it's not difficult, commit yourself and\n");
            printf("you will make it.\n");
        }
    }while(yes==0);
    
    if(yes==1){
        do{
            printf("-----------------------------------------------2.5\n");
            printf("Enter circumference: ");
            scanf("%f",&cp);
            if(cp>13){
                printf("tray again");
            }
            if(cp<8){
                printf("try again");
            }
        }while(cp<8 || cp>13);
    }
    
    printf("-----------------------------------------------3\n");                                      
    printf("Select country:\n");
    printf("1.Austria\n2.Belgium\n3.Bulgaria\n4.Cyprus\n5.Croatia\n");
    do{
        printf("N° ");
        scanf("%d",&country);
        if(country>5){
            printf("Wrong value\n");
            printf("Try Again\n");
        }
    }while(country==0 || country>5);
    
    printf("Summary:\n");
    printf("Length: %fcm\n",lp);
    if(yes==1){
        printf("Circumference: %fcm\n",cp);
    }
    else if(country==1){
        printf("Country: Austria");
    }
    else if(country==2){
        printf("Country: Belgium");
    }
    else if(country==3){
        printf("Country: Bulgaria");
    }
    else if(country==4){
        printf("Country: Cyprus");
    }
    else if(country==5){
        printf("Country: Croatia");
    }
    
    printf("Is it correct?: ");
    scanf("%s",correct);
    if(!strcmp(correct,"no")){
        printf("What do you want to change?:\n");
        printf("1.Length 2.Circumference 3.Country\n");
        do{
            printf("N° ");
            scanf("%d",&mod);
            if(mod>3){
                printf("Wrong Value\n");
                printf("Try Again\n");
            }
        }while(mod==0 || mod>3);
    }

    return 0;
}

float FunLength(float *lp){
    
    float temp=0;
    
    printf("Enter Length::\n");
    do{
        scanf("%f",&temp);
        *lp=temp;
        if(*lp>22){
                printf("Try Again\n");
        } 
        if(*lp<8){
                printf("Try Again\n");
        }
    }while(*lp>22 || *lp<8);
    return *lp;
}
```

So that's my code, that compare user sizes with european average sizes. I Would use function and structure. I think I'm gonna use structure with the comparison with every nation. Right now I would use function to make the program more "reusable". The problem is that the following function `float FunLength(float *lp)` is not working. What am I doing wrong? Also I wanna do the same thing with point 2 and 3, using a function. Please help me, and if you have some advice for the current code or for continuing it, i will appreciate.

Comment: In your code you prototype `float FunLength(float *lp);`, but the function is actually defined as FunLung`.   Also, because the value `lp` is being modified and returned through the parameter, the prototype `float FunLung(float *lp){` could be changed to a void return: `void FunLung(float *lp){`

Comment: Yep was my error, i fix it. Actually the code compiles. In the esecution of the program the fuction is avoided. I have tried to change float to void but compiler show me several errors.

Comment: Not sure how to help you with that last comment.  Be specific if you are describing a problem that you need help with :)

Comment: `code.c:23:11: error: conflicting types for ‘FunLength’`
`code.c:16:10: note: previous declaration of ‘FunLength’ was here`
`code.c:179:7: error: conflicting types for ‘FunLength’`
`code.c:16:10: note: previous declaration of ‘FunLength’ was here`
These are the error if i change float to void.

Comment: If i run the code just how i wrote it, it work, but the function it is as if it were not performed. The program just jump to the do cycle of circumference, then continue and at the summary, lenght line show 0(value of initialization).

Comment: @FedericoAmato: All the code taking the user input is really unnecessary to the problem. Please consider removing it to make the amount of code you are asking us to read to be much smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*conflicting types for ‘FunLength’ code.c:16:10: note: previous declaration of ‘FunLength’ was here*

In your code example, you are prototyping `FunLength()` twice.  *Remove* one or the other:

```
float FunLength(float *lp);/// here

      
printf("Please follow the steps:\n")
                                                                
printf("------------------------------------------------ 1\n");
printf("Enter Lenght:\n");
float FunLength(float *lp);///and here
```

And then, per the conversation in comments, make all definitions consistent with each other, and such that they support what you are doing:

Change the following:

```
float FunLength(float *lp);//prototype
```

To:

```
void FunLength(float *lp);
```

And:

```
float FunLength(float *lp){//function definition
```

To:

```
void FunLength(float *lp){
```

And because the function is now `void`, remove its return statement:

```
    //return *lp;
}
```

*but the function it is as if it were not performed.*

`FunLength()` is not performed because it is not called anywhere.   Once you decide where you will call it, call it like this:

(simplified `main()` function)

```
int main(void)
{
    float val = 0.0;
    FunLength(&val);
    printf("%f\n", val);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I have changed float with void and remove *lp from `return *lp;`. Than i call the function using `&lp` between brackets. Now it work, i will use same procedure for next  steps, thanks again :)